# character variable storing issue with scanf

Tags: c++, c, char, scanf, cin

I am trying a simple program which will create a linked lists and display the elements afterwards.
In this program, i am using a `char` variable `ch` to store yes/no for entering more nodes in the linked lists.
Consider the following program:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
  #include<malloc.h>  
struct node
{
    int num;
    struct node *next;
};
struct node *start=NULL;
int main()
{
    struct node *ptr,*new_node;
    int data,i;
    char ch;
    do
    {
        printf("Enter node value:");
        scanf("%d",&data);
        new_node=(struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        new_node->num=data;
        if(start==NULL)
        {
            new_node->next=NULL;
            start=new_node;
        }
        else
        {
            ptr=start;
            while(ptr->next!=NULL)
                ptr=ptr->next;
            ptr->next=new_node;
            new_node->next=NULL;
        }
        printf("Want to enter more nodes (Y/N)?");
        scanf("%c",&ch);
    }while((ch=='y')||(ch=='Y'));
    printf("\nThe entered elements in the linked lists is as follows:\n");
    ptr=start;
    i=1;
    while(ptr->next!=NULL)
    {
        printf("Node %d is %d\n",i,ptr->num);
        i++;
        ptr=ptr->next;
    }
    printf("Node %d is %d\n",i,ptr->num);
    return 0;
}
```

Now the above program is storing `10'\n'` in `ch` on entering `y` and as a result `do while` loop is terminated;
but when i am using `cin` instead of `scanf()` , then the above program is working properly.
so please anyone help me to explain why `scanf()` is not able to store `y` in `ch` ?

Comment: thank you so much @user3121023 ; could you please explain why `scanf()` is not working without giving any space?

Comment: Just as a side note: It is unsafe to use `scanf` without checking the return value. See this page for further information: [A beginners' guide away from scanf()](http://sekrit.de/webdocs/c/beginners-guide-away-from-scanf.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure of the reason but just put a space in your `scanf("%c",&ch)` and it will start working.
Just change it to `scanf(" %c",&ch)`
You can check if there is a reason somewhere for this and comment it out but for now this will help you. Just a guess it might be that the new character read by `ch` is new line which terminates it there itself.